# Strings from NSUserDefaults not visible, xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7, nsuserdefaults

Today I upgraded to Xcode 7.3, and I also started getting odd behavior from NSUserDefaults. I don't know if they're related. String values I store in defaults are not visible upon retrieval but they have length and support substring extraction:

```
(lldb) po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:UDEmail]

(lldb) po [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:UDEmail] length]
0x00000014

(lldb) po [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:UDEmail] substringFromIndex:0]
david.uzzell@att.net
```

Some methods that receive these strings act as if I have passed in a nil value. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Confirmed here. Must be a debugger error.

Comment: I can't expand custom object by debuger and use LLDB to read data

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly an answer but if you call the "description" method, witch is declared in the NSObject class, you can see the value of the property.